# Failure on node-sass install

Tags: npm, gulp, node-sass

I am trying to install node sass to run an existing project and I keep getting the same error.

```
2481 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp-sass"
2482 verbose node v16.20.0
2483 verbose npm  v8.3.1
2484 error code 1
2485 error path C:\Users\user\Documents\PROJECTS\Service Application\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\node-sass
2486 error command failed
2487 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
```

I am not sure where the actual error message is in the stack but i think it might be here:

```
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base)
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64)
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing a Windows SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.* or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Some required components are missing, not using this installation
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
2489 error gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools
```

If you have any idea's of need more of the stack trace please comment and I will update the question.

Here are the python compile args:

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Service Application\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Service Application\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Service Application\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\.node-gyp\\16.20.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\jfletcher\\.node-gyp\\16.20.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Service Application\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\user\\.node-gyp\\16.20.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Service Application\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Service Application\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
```